# Can't click checkbox element with Selenium C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I have problem clicking on a checkbox. When I try to use the webdriver click() function it says that it can't locate the element, then I try to use a JS execution which I test in the browser console and it work, but when I try to execute it through the selenium webdriver, it don't work again.

The JS function is:

```
webDriver.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById(\"container_form_containers_21_use\").click();");
```

The error I receive from this is "

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: Cannot read
>   property 'click' of null"

and the other normal selenium function I use for the click is:

`webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='uniform container_form_containers_21_use']")).Click()`;

The error I receive from this is

> "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='uniform -
>   container_form_containers_21_use']"}"

Note that

```
document.getElementById(\"container_form_containers_21_use\").click();
```

works fine when I execute it in the browser console.

Comment: You need to ensure correct the XPath location of the element. If selenium throw "NoSuchElementException", you must check FindElement method. You can use `GetElementById("container_form_containers_21_use") method instead of GetElementByXPath.

Comment: Even if I try to use ID it's still throw error that the element cannot be located OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"container_form_containers_21_use"}. And I know that find element works, because I use it other steps before the error in the same test case and everything is with the function.

Comment: I think xpath issue

Comment: webDriver.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('container_form_containers_21_use').click();"); can you try this code? Maybe there is a problem with an escape character '\' in C#

Comment: webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("container_form_containers_21_use")).Click(); can you try this ?

Comment: The result is the same if I use ' or \". I first thought it was xpath issue, but it's not. I use the same xpath for the same step with a php selenium script, but it does not work in c# (I need to use c# because i do some performance checks with neoload)

Comment: @OMANSK yes I try it and it still throws an error

Comment: @ValentinRaynov Update the question with the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm remember correctly, you can't click the checkbox, you need to send space key.

```
webDriver.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('container_form_containers_21_use\')").SendKeys(Keys.Space);
```